# Possible ways of reusage of views in Angular

Tags: templates, angularjs

Lets say I have html view like `<div ng-controler="contr">....</div>`  and a js controler. Supposed that i want to use this view on bottom left and right top of my main page, in the center of one of the sub pages and so on... What are my best options of reusage? I saw that i can inject the whole html into a string and call "compile" like [this](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24compile) but this does not seem "elegant"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put it in a spearate html file, or add to the template cache, and include it with the [ng-include directive](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive%3angInclude). I'll automatically create a new scope.

```html
<ng-include src="'template.html'"></ng-include>
<ng-include src="'template.html'"></ng-include>

<script type="text/ng-template" id="template.html">
    <div ng-controler="contr">....</div>
</script>
```